# Bootstrap 4 styles not loaded using spring boot with thymeleaf

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I'm having problems with Bootstrap 4: styles are not loaded into page. I'm using Spring Boot, Maven and THymeleaf.

In my HTML file i have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
```

I have also in my Maven dependencies

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

When, for example, i try to add a bootstrap card or button I see them in basic html style.
So, what's my problem?
thanks for help

Comment: did you add bootstrap CDN link on the ```<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"></head>``` tag ?

if when this working fine then make sure your maven dependency relative path is correct?

Comment: yes, the path is fine and the link is in the head tag but it's still broken

Comment: did you config web-jars in your configuration class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the way you can add these dependencies in your `pom.xml` file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
    <version>0.30</version>
</dependency>
```

When using `Spring Framework version 4.2 or higher`, it will automatically detect the `webjars-locator` library on the classpath and use it to automatically resolve the version of any WebJars assets.
And simply add into your view page  tags

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}">
```

And also add these bottom of your `<body></body>` tags

```
<script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/webjars/popper.js/umd/popper.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
```

I hope you are in bootstrap now. Happy coding.

---

For better understanding what I said to refer this- https://www.baeldung.com/maven-webjars

Comment: I dont know why, but now works properly with the script tags you posted but in the <head> tag. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try (similar to) this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
        th:href="@{webjars/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
```

Things to notice:

1. Version of Bootstrap. Your version in html is different than your pom version.
2. You have to use "webjars/..." inside curly braces and not "/webjars/...". Remove leading slash (/).

Take a look at the sample [here](https://github.com/ajkr195/Code-Incubator/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/fragments/header.html).